# Sleep mode rendering times

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

So far I haven't needed to keep rendering over night but when I do get to that, I would like to know if blender continues to render when my laptop goes into sleep mode. I'm too scared to try it in case it screws up the render...

Comment: I'm running W10 in my laptop and it doesn't got into sleep mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing happens during sleep mode, not even the operating system is running.
Blender will **not** render because the computer is not powered on.

During *Stand By* the computer is in a low powered state with minimal energy consumption and little to no activity.

Depending on your version of the operating system the computer will either store the session in RAM memory or down to the hard drive reducing the power consumption to virtually zero.

If it serves as consolation Blender generally prevents Windows based operating systems, at least, from entering Stand By while running, so your renders will theoretically not be interrupted **if** the computer never enters sleep.